# concrete5, "failed to create cache path" error when trying to load admin site

Tags: concrete5

Our developers did something, but "didn't."

We have one database and one Concrete5 installation and 76 websites. All work OK, but 2 websites. The websites load fine, but can't load the admin site and get "failed to create cache path" error when trying to do so. When going into the code for this error (https://docs.mnkras.com/tedivm_2stash_2src_2_stash_2_utilities_8php_source.html)
it shows that it is looking for the proper path and permissions and if not found, then give the error.

The cache folder has been emptied and deleted.
Permissions have been checked and they match that on the other websites.
Logs don't show any indication that anything is wrong

Some other things have been done to troubleshoot, but I'll have to wait for that person to come back from a meeting to fill you in on that.

To us system admins, obviously something has been changed for these two sites and it has to do with path and permissions, but don't know where to look for those changes since the manual check on the website folders seems seem like all is in order. So perhaps something got changed in code.

We have searched online, in the Concrete5 forums, and here for an answer and can't find anything that would fix it or point to source of error.

No updates have been done.  Supposedly no changes to code have been done.  It just stopped loading and started giving this error.  Since it is only 2 websites affected, it goes to reason that something was changed for the code/settings/configurations for these two websites and not the others or Concrete5 in general.  Not system wide.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what c5 version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that SeLinux was in Enforcing.  It was preventing the site from writing to cache.

Answer (score 0):

Enable full debugging and output by adding this array to the returned array in the application/config/concrete.php file:

```
'debug' => [
    'detail' => 'debug',
    'display_errors' => true,
],
```

Then see what the actual $path and $permissions parameters are being passed to the checkFileSystemPermissions() method call.

Look at the application/config/*.php and application/config/generated_overrides/*.php files for anything that might affect these 2.

Try removing all files and directories from under application/files/cache/, but leave cache/ there (writeable by the webserver) and try connecting to those sites from a new private browser window/tab.

Those 2 might also have a package installed that could be affecting things.

I doubt you have one database (maybe you meant one server), but take a quick look in their databasename.Config tables and make sure nothing weird is in there...